# java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter msg must not be empty

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, barcode4j

I´m getting this strange error when trying to put a barcode in a report with Ireport.

I´ve already created a parameter named 'msg' but I keep getting this error. What´s the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the barcode provider to Barbecue and everything is running fine.

Answer (score 0):

main reason of this **java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter msg must not be empty** error is because obviously from word itself null pointer exception. Your parameter 'msg' is null or doesn't have value. Be sure you it catch the value your passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for what I could see, many have the same issue. I am no good in Jasper but here is my solution to it.

Cause: The issue comes due to absence of value in the barcode property in appearance under print when section for the option: Print When Expression.

Solution: Caste a boolean return for the barcode value, with something like this: $F{BARCODE}.contains( $F{BARCODE} )

Short explanation: This value is passed, in my understanding as MSG parameter to the barcode generator barcode4j. When null, it throws exception as expected. So we need to set a value. The value expected is of type boolean. I had a field that was named BARCODE. so I just put a code as above which says check if Barcode string has Barcode string value. WHich is like saying when 1=1. This returns a boolean value. Hence all conditions are met. When the field has a value, you will see the barcode in the output.

Why I broke my head on this solution and not just replaced it with barbecue: When i changed the barcode type, the format changed and the guys using the output were just not happy as visually it looked different. So I had to use barcode4j and I had to fix the issue. Hope it helps. Cheers.